# socket.io connection error "chat.js:41 WebSocket connection to 'wss://authbackend-74z0.onrender.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: "

Tags: reactjs, node.js, sockets, connection, chat

How can I resolve the WebSocket connection error when connecting from a React client to a Node.js backend hosted on Render, where Socket.io and Express are both listening on different ports within the same index.js file? Is it necessary to use two separate URLs for Socket.io and Express APIs, and if so, how can I obtain two URLs for a server where Socket.io and Express are both listening on the different URLs, it works well on the local machine.

resolve the socket connection error "chat.js:41 WebSocket connection to 'wss://authbackend-74z0.onrender.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: " in the client side while using backend hosted url

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.